# unable to list windows phone applications signed with MFP 7

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

We have a problem when trying to list the application signed in the applicationcenter/installers/html.

We get the unsigned applicationCenter app for Windows Phone from the MFP Server repository.

We get a certificate from Symantec (who delivers the certificates for Windows applications).

We signed the applicationCenter app for Windows Phone from the Windows Phone sdk using the certificate delivered by Symantec.

We install the signed applicationCenter app in the applicatonCenter console choosing `Installer` option.

We generated a token with AETGenerator tool that we uploaded and registered in the application center console for the applicationCenter app for Windows Phone.

We connected to `http://hostname:portnumber/applicationcenter/installers.html` from the Windows Phone device and we accept the token.

Then we refresh the screen and get a message that the list of application is empty whereas we should see the applicationCenter app signed for WindowsPhone.

Does anyone ever face this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure to follow the instructions precisely according to the user documentation at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_ac_install_client_wp8_dev.html?

Comment: We did exactly the same process ! We could list the token on the mobile device, add the token on the device and add the company account (So steps 1 to 7 are ok). Then when we go to "installers" tab as mentioned in step 8 of your link, we cannont select the mobile client application in the list of available applications and we get the following message: "No available application..."

Comment: We should see at least the Windows phone appCenter version we previously signed and added to the appCenter console ...

Comment: For an application to be listed in the installers.html  page it must have both the "Installer" and "Active" attributes checked in the Application Center console. Maybe are you missing the "Active" attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see the Windows Phone App Center Client when you open the AppCenter Console in the browser? Can you add any IPA file and mark it as Installer? If you then see the IPA file in the installers.html page of the Windows Phone Device, you are running into an incompatibility that was recently introduced by Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1.

This problem was fixed by an ifix. Depending on your version, you need the following ifix:

- 7.0.0.x: IF20150407-1506
- 6.3.0.x: IF20150403-1749
- 6.2.0.x: IF20150407-0051
- 6.1.0.x: IF20150407-0051

Note that the first 8 digits of the ifix are a date. Any ifix with a later date is also ok. Ifixes can be obtained from https://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/

See also http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI36918

Comment: Thank you very much Georg Sander, we have fixed the issue following your recommendation. So we installed the latest ifix available from fix central (the latest one was 7.0.0.0-MFPF-Server-IF201507291801) using IBM Installation Manager.