# Windows Phone Installer For MobileFirst Application Center

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

i have uploaded the windows phone installer (Mordor.xap) in my application center console,

but when i tried to access the installers.html, i only got installers for ios and ipad. There is no installer for windows phone.

My question :

1. why my windows phone device cannot detect the installer?
2. For the token, do i must copied manually on my device?

Answer (score 2):

About question 1: Same situation as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589366/unable-to-list-windows-phone-applications-signed-with-mfp-7).

You are running into an incompatibility that was recently introduced by Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1.

This problem was fixed by an ifix. Depending on your version, you need the following ifix:

```
7.0.0.x: IF20150407-1506
6.3.0.x: IF20150403-1749
6.2.0.x: IF20150407-0051
6.1.0.x: IF20150407-0051
```

Note that the first 8 digits of the ifix are a date. Any ifix with a later date is also ok. Ifixes can be obtained from https://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/

See also http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI36918

About question 2: If you talk about the Application Enrollment Token (AET), please follow the instructions found [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_ac_install_client_wp8_dev.html).